# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker throwing System.ObjectDisposedException exception in Blazor .Net 5.0

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, blazor-server-side, .net-5

I'm trying to use the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/dotnet) in my Blazor server-side app.

I create the credentials following the instructions:

```
UserCredential credential;

using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
      string credPath = "token.json";
      credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
          GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
          Scopes,
          "user",
          CancellationToken.None,
          new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
}
```

When calling the `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` I get the following error thrown:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Safe handle has been closed.
> Object name: 'SafeHandle'.'

Is this to be expected? Can I simply ignore this error, or is there anything I should do about it?